# DMV issues for databases in compatibility_level "80"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have numerous databases in compatibility_level of 80 (SQL Server 2000);
I need to execute the following:

```
select 
    sf.fileid, sf.groupid, sf.name, sf.filename, mf.database_id 
from 
    sys.sysfiles sf
JOIN 
    sys.master_files mf ON sf.filename = mf.physical_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_os_volume_stats (mf.database_id, sf.fileid)
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I cannot change the compatibility mode and I have no idea how I can run this specific script for my database from the context of master db.

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired results?    what is sys.dm_os_volume_stats?

Comment: SQL Server **2000** is more than old and deprecated - time to upgrade (even just your compat level) ! And SQL Server 2000 didn't have any of the `sys.` catalog views - you won't be able to use this query. If you **absolutely** must have this for SQL Server 2000 - you'll have to rewrite the `sys.sysfiles` etc. to the ancient views there were, and you can forget about the `dm_os_volume_stats` since nothing like that (DMV - dynamic management views) existed back then. ....

Comment: Most database-specific views can be prefixed with the actual database name (`mydb.sys.sysfiles`) and then run from another database with a higher compat level. Where this is not practical, you will simply have to bite the bullet and upgrade. Upping the compatibility level is very rarely a big deal and you'll have to do it at one point anyway. Consult [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680) for possible issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CROSS APPLY" is not allowed in earlier versions of the SQL as well in databases running in older compatibility models.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2000 there were no 'sys' files. Many had equivalents and you can see a good chart at:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1037/system-information-in-sql-server-2000-vs-sql-server-2005/

In 2000 for example there was a dbo.sysfiles but no sys.sysfiles. These tables do not necessarily contain the same columns.....